# Example of non-regular Riemannian covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

I am looking for an example of a finite Riemannian covering map $\pi: (\tilde{M}, \tilde{g}) \to (M, g)$, where $M$ is closed, which is not a regular covering map. Any hints or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just take a finite non-regular covering of manifolds $\pi : \tilde{M} \to M$, choose a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ and set $\tilde{g} = \pi^*g$?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Can you give me an example, please?